# Multiple IScroll in the same page, without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, function, web, iscroll

How initialize multiple IScroll elements in the same page without jQuery. I want initialize a plugin automatically for each IScroll element in this page.

i try:

```
var scrolls = document.querySelectorAll(".text-wrap");
var scroll_ar = [];
for (var i = 0; i < scrolls.length; i++) {
    var scroll = scrolls[i];

    scroll_ar[i] = new IScroll(scroll, {
        scrollX:false,
        scrollY:true
    });

    scroll_ar[i].on('beforeScrollStart', function(e){
        pageScroll.disable();
    });

    scroll_ar[i].on('scrollEnd', function(e){
        pageScroll.enable();
    });
```

but doesn't work :(

Comment: on() is jQuery isn't it?  I think you want addEventListener()

Comment: if i have one iscroll element and use this code without for cycle it's work..